# Time is not stored in the mapping

Tags: solidity, contract-development, mapping, timestamp

I wrote a function to exchange an offer by an amount of ether. After checking the value of ether sent and the cost of the 
offering, I record the subscription time in a mapping. My problem is that when I send a transaction with the command:

`offer.subscribeOffer.sendTransaction(0,{from:eth.accounts[0], to:0x2333a7124d57795757239f0f86990ca9f429e032, value: 2,gas:4000000})` 
[image: the console shot]

nothing is saved in the mapping, neither the address nor the time.

This is my contract code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.9;

contract Offer {

address public owner;
struct Offer {
    string title;
    string description;
    uint  offerTime;
    mapping (address => uint) subscribers;
    mapping (uint => address) subscribersAddress;
    mapping (uint => uint) nbrSubscribersPerID;
    uint price;
}

Offer[] public  offers;


// add offer
function addOffer(string  description1, string title1, uint price1,uint offerTime1) 
  returns (uint, string, string, uint, uint) {
    uint offerID = offers.length++;
    Offer o = offres[offreID];

    o.description = description1;
    o.offerTime=offerTime1;
    o.title = title1;
    o.price = price1;
    return (offerID, offers[offerID].description, offers[offerID].title, offers[offerID].price, 
      offers[offerID].offerTime);
}

//return the  number of offers 
function returnNbroffer() constant returns(uint) {
    uint nbr_offer =offers.length;
    return(nbr_offer);
}

function subscribeOffer(uint offerID) public payable  returns(address,uint,address)   {

      Offer o = offers[offerID];
      uint i=0;
      uint count=0;
         if (msg.value>= o.price)
           { address addre=msg.sender;
             offres[offerID].subscribersAddress[count=++i]=msg.sender;
             offres[offerID].subscribers[msg.sender]=now;
             return(addre,offers[offerID].subscribers[msg.sender],offers[offerID].subscribersAddress[i]);


            }
    offers[offerID].nbreSubscribersParID[offerID]=count;



}
  function expirationOffer(uint offerID) constant  returns(bool,uint,uint)
  { 
     Offer o = offers[offerID];
     bool expire=false;
     uint timenow=now;
     uint timeSpent=offres[offerID].subscribers[msg.sender]+o.offerTime ;
     if (timenow > timeSpent )
       {expire=true;}
   return(expire,timenow,timeSpent);
   }
 }
```

Comment: Doesn't compile. offer or offres? Where does o.cout come from? Suggest working it out in https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity

Comment: These are typos, I have edited them! Yes it compile

Comment: try to add an event to check, besides Rob is right your code is erroneous doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried your contract after correcting some typos :

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.9;

contract Offer {

address public owner;
struct Offer {
    string title;
    string description;
    uint  offerTime;
    mapping (address => uint) subscribers;
    mapping (uint => address) subscribersAddress;
    mapping (uint => uint) nbrSubscribersPerID;
    uint price;
}

Offer[] public  offers;


// add offer
function addOffer(string  description1, string title1, uint price1,uint offerTime1) 
  returns (uint, string, string, uint, uint) {
    uint offerID = offers.length++;
    Offer o = offers[offerID];

    o.description = description1;
    o.offerTime=offerTime1;
    o.title = title1;
    o.price = price1;
    return (offerID, offers[offerID].description, offers[offerID].title, offers[offerID].price, 
      offers[offerID].offerTime);
}

//return the  number of offers 
function returnNbroffer() constant returns(uint) {
    uint nbr_offer =offers.length;
    return(nbr_offer);
}

function subscribeOffer(uint offerID) public payable  returns(address,uint,address)   {

      Offer o = offers[offerID];
      uint i=0;
      uint count=0;
         if (msg.value>= o.price)
           { address addre=msg.sender;
             offers[offerID].subscribersAddress[count=++i]=msg.sender;
             offers[offerID].subscribers[msg.sender]=now;
             return(addre,offers[offerID].subscribers[msg.sender],offers[offerID].subscribersAddress[i]);


            }
    offers[offerID].nbrSubscribersPerID[offerID]=count;



}
  function expirationOffer(uint offerID) constant  returns(bool,uint,uint)
  { 
     Offer o = offers[offerID];
     bool expire=false;
     uint timenow=now;
     uint timeSpent=offers[offerID].subscribers[msg.sender]+o.offerTime ;
     if (timenow > timeSpent )
       {expire=true;}
   return(expire,timenow,timeSpent);
   }
 }
```

I think you get a o because you don't send much ether to your contract because in your function `subscribeOffer` you set a condition if `(msg.value>= o.price)` so your transaction should hold more ethers thant the offer price otherwise you get 0. I've tried using solidity browser and it works fine.
[image]

Comment: thanks for your help! when I add an offer with price=0, it works well but when I change the offer price to 1 for example it doesn't work ,while I send ether enough in value. `offer.subscribeOffer.sendTransaction(2,{from:"0x9f6b29ef03bd9134481d5ebf70b702b6cb36224e",to:0x6a029d9382b175b3ca7594c7aa2d10a95907b450,gas:40000000,value:2452225})`

Comment: It works when I hold more ether in value! I am so grateful :)